# Xamarin IOS Get List of files in All Directories

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working in a Xamarin IOS project.

I am creating a custom file explorer. So I want to read files from Documents, Downloads Images and other folder files.

Is this possible to get all files list in all folders in IOS?

Please suggest which folders are accessible.

Comment: I suggest you actually do your own research first. How about you just recursively attempt to read files on the file system. Then you can quickly discover what you have access to...

Comment: I saw the file system example here https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/main/FileSystemSampleCode. but it only reads directory from "./". but I don't know how to get access to Download, Document, and Images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is document about file system in iOS, you can get information about how to access file through this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system